# Unable to inflate a layout on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

Hi I am trying to show a layout when a button is pressed but the layout is never shown. No exception is thrown for some reason. The button is located inside an activity. The button is called and declared and it works. The calling of the layout is just additional action to the button.

Here is my code to inflate the layout:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View error = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_search_no_results,null);
```

Comment: where you are adding `error` to current visible views?

Comment: No i don't want to add it I want it to be shown as a different window

Comment: To show different window you will need to use PopUpWindow,AlertDialog or a new Activity to show `error` view

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
rv.addView(error);
```

Where rv is your parent layout.