# Unable to inflate layout in Async Task

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Hi all I have a bit of a weird problem with my app I am populating a list in a RecyclerView using an Async Task. Everything works OK but when there is no data to populate I want to inflate another layout to show an error message.

```
public class generateAds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //Filling the list -This part is OK
    }         
    //Here is my problem  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(ads.size() > 0)
        {
            if (isFirstSearch)
            {
                isFirstSearch = false;                    
                cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(context, ads);                   
                recyclerViewZone.setAdapter(cardAdapter);                   
                recyclerViewZone.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ads.size(); i++) {
                    cardAdapter.add(ads.get(i), cardAdapter.getItemCount());
                }
            }
            generatedAdsFromScroll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //This doesn't inflate 
            try
            {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection,container,false);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); //No exception thrown for some reason
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So in my onPostExecute After I check if the list ADS contains something it should go and inflate my layout. The weird thing is that it does read it, but no layout is shown on the screen it doesnt throw any exceptions of any sort. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you show the entire Activity code ? Specifically what you do with rootView.

Comment: rootView is declared as a view: View rootView; no need for the whole code

Comment: What is rootView? What you need to do is hide your ListView/RecyclerView if it is empty and then inflate the layout of your choice in it's place. Once inflated you still need to add that view somewhere

Comment: I just cant understand why its not inflating its reading it (I have debugged it) but nothing is shown on the screen. And there is no exception

Comment: If I add recyclerViewZone.setVisibility(View.GONE); before I inflate it again nothing is shown :/

Comment: See my edit. inflating it is fine, but where is it going? For example if I wanted it to be the be header of my recyclerView I would go recyclerView.addHeaderView(rootView); then it would show up. It needs to be set somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to inflate a layout on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901244/unable-to-inflate-a-layout-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only inflating the view , but not adding the view to any viewgroup. Try addView(View v) to add a view.

Comment: container is the viewgroup

Comment: use container.addview(rootview).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is only a guess because you don't show your entire code, I think you never set `rootView` as the content of your `Activity`.

Instead of this

```
try {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection,container,false);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //No exception thrown for some reason
}
```

do this

```
setContentView(R.layout.error_internet_connection);
```

Alternatively, you could declare the `View` you want to show when there is no connection inside the main layout, have it hidden by default and call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on that `View` and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the rest of the layout when no connection is available.

**EDIT** : after seeing your edit about the class not being part of an Activity, your code should not compile. To have this work properly, the best method is probably to leave the `Activity` handle its Views.

Things you need to do :

- Change your `AsyncTask` from `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>` to
  `AsyncTask<String, Void, ReturnObject>` where `ReturnObject` is the data
  produced by the `AsyncTask`. Change the `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` to
  `onPostExecute(ReturnObject returnObject)` as well.
- Declare an interface `ReturnDataHandler` in your `AsyncTask`, having one
  `handleData(ReturnObject returnObject)` method, and have your `Activity`
  implement it. Declare one instance as member variable of the
  `AsyncTask` (mDataHandler) and take one instance as constructor
  argument. Pass your `Activity` when starting the `AsyncTask`. That way,
  in `onPostExecute`, you simply do
  `mDataHandler.handleData(returnObject)`, and it is the method
  `handleData(returnObject)` that will handle the `Views` based on the
  result of the `AsyncTask`...

Comment: Opas you are right I forgot to mention this is not an activity this is a class

Comment: If your edit is complete, recyclerViewZone.setAdapter should not even compile because recyclerViewZone is not declared anywhere. Are you sure you are showing the complete code ?

Comment: ... That is an interesting theory but do i say that everything else is working as it should?

Answer (score 0):

When changing `Adapter`'s data, in this case, `CardAdapter`s data, you need to call its `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to allow all views that are bound to this adapter to update and redraw itself. Documentation from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) :

> public void notifyDataSetChanged()
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.